# What does die print?

Tags: perl, die

The following is the code that I tried to execute

```
$a=0;  
if($a==0){die  print"zero"};
```

and I get output as follows

```
1 at test.pl line 2  
Zero
```

I am wondering what is `1` that is printed first, is it something like die is printing the value returned by the if statement? Any help would be appriciated

Comment: It prints the return value of `print "zero"`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In

```
die print "zero";
```

`die` will use the return value of `print "zero";`, which is `1`, as its argument. So you see the `1 at ...` message.

By default, the `STDOUT` of interactive program is line buffered, but `STDERR` is unbuffered, that is why you see the `1 at ...` (on stderr) first, and `zero` (on stdout) later. If you change that `print "zero"` to `print "zero\n"`, you will see `zero` comes first.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, print function returned a 1 which die promptly inserted into its error message.

Control never returns to the if stmt.